# Magento2 - how to know when what parameter i have to pass in controller - _construct function

Tags: magento2, controllers, class, action

i was reading a book magento2 tutorial. When learning how to create module. 2 augments was receiving in _construct function of controller.

Actually i am talking about this 2

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
```

how to know when which augment i have to use? i.e when working with product, order, customer. for example i saw that in other tutorial for get product list i have to use some like productfactory

Below is complete code for that controller

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
$this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `RequestInterface`

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
  \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->request = $request;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){
       $value = $this->request->getParam('yourkey');
}
```

Your ajax call is like:

```
$.ajax({
      url: {Yourcontrollerurl},
      data: {yourkey: $('#yourHtmlTagID').val()},
      type: 'post',
      ---
      });
```

don't forgot to recompile.

Comment: hi can you help me of this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151482/magento2-custom-different-flat-shipping-charge-for-few-products

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request`

or can use

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('Your Variable Name')`

or

`use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;`

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
var_dump($post);
```

Comment: do you mean i can use this ----- \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request     ----              instead them    ---- \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

Comment: Apart from this 2 `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory` Add Request one in cortoller as @Chirag told in Answer

Comment: hi can you help me of this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151482/magento2-custom-different-flat-shipping-charge-for-few-products